# Modify Sitemap in CRM 2011 - changes are not visible

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working with CRM 2011. I am a beginner in CRM family. As part of exercise I modified the Site map of the Web interface of CRM by making changes in `customizations.xml` file. For that purpose I exported the Site Map entity which locates in Client Extension. Before modifying the site map, I saved the origional site map solution. The changes were successful after importing the solution.
Now, I wanted to import the original site map solution and after successful Import and publishing, the changes are not rolled back(i.e the original site map interface is not appearing).

**Am I missing something here? Please suggest as I am clueless at this time.**

thanks

Comment: Are you importing the sitemap as a managed or unmanaged solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by a PC reboot. Still not able to trace down the root cause but customizations.xml was correct which i was providing :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have either not published your customization, or your "original" solution file does not contain the site map.  If you have more than one environment, you could be pushing to the wrong one accidentally.  I'd do a compare between your two customizations.xml files to make sure they are different.

Comment: I have compared the customizations.xml files and they are different. And I am 100% sure that I am giving correct customization.xml file (Default customization in CRM). My solution contains one folder named `WebResources` and three files `customizations.xml`,`[Content_Types].xml`, and `solution.xml`. I am importing it as a zip file via Solutions import feature. After that I also publish the newly imported solution.