# SiteMap is not updated after solution import - CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have one interesting problem here. After importing managed solution in CRM, SiteMap is not updated.

SiteMap is included in solution. I checked in customization.xml file, and everything seems fine (appropriate groups are included as well as SubAreas). After import in CRM I published solution, cleaned browser cache, tried with different browsers,... no success.

Checked with [SiteMap Editor](http://sitemapeditor.codeplex.com/) , and those changes are not visible. (!?!?!)

Everything else from solution is applied successfully.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197235/modify-sitemap-in-crm-2011-changes-are-not-visible) is also not helpful. Machine is restarted, solution reimported, but again, without success.

Any advice about this?

Thanx!

Comment: strange issue, which rollup is installed? maybe is a bug of an older version.

Comment: I have rollup 13 (5.0.9690.3448) installed on both machines

Comment: I checked the fixes of ru14 and ru15, but nothing indicates an eventual fix for this kind of problems. Can you try to create a new solution containing only the sitemap and import?

Comment: yap, already tried that case, but with same result. It's like CRM totally ignore SiteMap component in solution...